# PayPal Payment Data Transfer to Angular Web App

Tags: angularjs, paypal, checkout, data-transfer

I got a quick question:

I want to implement a `PayPal` checkout.
I found out I can use `PayPal Payment Data Transfer`.
If somebody pays me I want `PayPal` to send me some information back like: `User_ID and Item_ID`.

How do I post this Data in my `PayPal` Button and how can I consume this data after I got redirected to my page.

Btw I got an `AngularJs` Web App and I want to consume the return data in my return page Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

PayPal Instant Payment Notification:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

You can store your information in the PayPal custom input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$user_id" />
```

Consume it in your php listener file:

```
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
```

Tutorial how to set this up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IfwYMI25L8

I hope I could help with this Question-Thread